# string to list of string and integers

Tags: python, string, list

I have a string `'3,M,8,M'` and want to convert it into a list `[3, 'M', 8, 'M']`. Does anyone have any idea how I can do this?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine split with list comprehension:

```
'3,M,8,M'.split(',')
# Out[4]: ['3', 'M', '8', 'M']

[int(x) if x.isdigit() else x for x in '3,M,8,M'.split(',')]
# Out[5]: [3, 'M', 8, 'M']
```

Comment: Since `isnumeric()` will be true if there are characters like fractions, which will not work with `int()`, perhaps `isdigit()` would be a better choice.

Comment: @FredLarson, interesting. I had to look it up, but in this case there is nearly no difference between both. because `isnumeric()` does NOT check for floats the difference ist that isnumeric can also detect digits of other languages like this: `'一二三四五'.isnumeric()` in contrast to: `'一二三四五'.isdigit()` Unfortunately float is not covered by any of them, not even by `.isdecimal()`